# Is it possible for a global product to have store dependent custom options?

Tags: multistore, custom-options, sku

I am working on a multisite/store/storeview Magento site where we sell the same products in each substore, but need to have store dependent decoration options for each product. The product in each store must have the same SKU.

Example:

User A is in Store A, and selects product with SKU 12345. User A sees custom options for size, color, and Store A dependent decoration.

User B is in Store B and selects same product with SKU 12345. User B sees same custom options for size and color (custom options template is shared between stores), and then sees Store B dependent decoration options.

What is the best way to get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution that works great for solving my problem:

**Step One:** I created a bundle product with the SKU, images, and details of the product that I would like to share across websites/storeviews. I made this bundle product available in all websites.

**Step Two:** I created the custom options as individual simple products that were only available in their respective categories(using separate sets of categories unique for each website), and set them to not be visible individually.

**Step Three:** I added ALL of the simple products ("decoration options") into a single bundle item option within the bundle created in step 1.

This results in a pseudo custom option in the form of a product list that is different depending no the store view in the front end.

This works because all products in my instance follow this format:

Bundle Product (SKU of main item)
 -BP custom option 1 (size)
 -BP custom option 2 (color)
 -Single product in bundle (store specific decoration that displays based on unique category view)

It's a weird solution, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

1. Either you use translations, you can translate the custom options in two different ways for each store.
2. Second idea: You create two custom options, and hide one of them in each store
3. You implement your own option, don't use custom options and you can do whatever you want.

Comment: 1. I will look into this and see if its viable for our setup  2. Can you clarify? I'm not aware of this being possible via admin panel - and development wise we have over 40 substores so I could see that being an issue.  3. Trying to avoid this scenario if possible :) Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: For 40 stores I think 2 is no option. I would opt for 3, it is implemented fast if you know what you are doing. What you can do for 2 is: Have your own theme/css file which just hides the option